# NoSuchCompilerException maven package

Tags: java, macos, maven, jersey

When trying to run `mvn clean package` I get the following error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-
plugin:3.6.0:compile (default-compile) on project rest-webapp: 
Execution default-compile of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:
3.6.0:compile failed: A required class was missing while executing 
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.0:compile: 
org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/manager/NoSuchCompilerException
```

I found numerous suggestions to delete everything in `~/.m2/repository`. Doing so does not fix the issue.

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.rest</groupId>
<artifactId>rest-webapp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>rest-webapp</name>

<build>
    <finalName>rest-webapp</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
        </plugin>   
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
        <version>6.0_ALPHA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-compiler-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
        <artifactId>plexus-compiler-manager</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.25</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>
        UTF-8
    </project.build.sourceEncoding>
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

I am using Mac OSX 10.11.6

$JAVA_HOME is  `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home`

$PATH is `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/opt/apache-maven-3.3.9/bin`

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The stack trace when I run `mvn clean package -X` is posted here:
http://pastebin.ca/3753171

Comment: Why adding plexus-compiler-api and plexus-compiler-manager as dependencies? That does not make sense...remove those dependencies...

Comment: Yeah I'm a little confused on what needs to be included in the pom and not. It was not working before I added them either. Thanks @khmarbaise

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to set up command line java in OS X is to use:

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8`
```

This not only sets the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, but also adjusts a bunch of links in `/usr/bin` so that:

```
[steve@Steves-MacBook-Pro ~]$ which java
/usr/bin/java
[steve@Steves-MacBook-Pro ~]$ which javac
/usr/bin/javac
```

applies to the version that you specify in the `/usr/libexec/java_home` call, therefore there is no need to add `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to your `$PATH`.

I'm guessing that you have never done this, so you're getting the Java tooling from `/usr/bin` which is trumping your $PATH environment because it appears before `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/bin`.

Comment: thanks for the response. I set JAVA_HOME as you said through .bash_profile, I also removed JAVA_HOME/bin from the path. I checked that both 'which' commands return the correct path. I am still getting the same error. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you get when you type `java -version` and `javac -version` in a new terminal window?

Comment: `java version "1.8.0_45"`
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)`
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)` 

`javac 1.8.0_45`

Comment: Please add the output of `mvn clean package -X` to your question. I built a little test project using your pom content and it works just fine with maven 3.0.5, 3.1.1, 3.2.5 and 3.3.9.

Comment: I added the stack trace. I guess I didn't mention before but I'm using maven 3.3.9

Comment: You seem to have the resources-plugin as a dependency (don't do that), but other than that the only difference between the output of my test app and yours is the java version - I'm using `1.8.0_112`. Did you install java by downloading the .dmg file from Oracle or from the "Java Control Panel"? Did you install maven 3.3.9 from an installer or from an unpacked tar.gz/zip file from the Apache Maven download site?

Comment: I installed maven from an unpacked tar.gz from the maven download site. I'm not as certain about Java but I believe it was from a .dmg file.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me is add

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
```